# What was the purpose of 'Pursuit of Happyness'

Tags: plot-explanation, the-pursuit-of-happyness

I heard that there was a history behind the movie 'Pursuit of Happyness', as this was the dream project of Will Smith.

I loved that movie and want to know the story. Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: do you want the story of the movie or history?

Comment: I want to have some story about the that time condition of Will Smith when he made the movie. I don't want to know about Chris Gardner, it's available in wikipedia already.

Comment: ask your question more specific buddy!!

Comment: Can you list where you 'heard' this information from?  Can you elaborate on your question at all?

Comment: Well, I heard that from my teacher when there was a movie-review session at our college. I just wanted to confirm if there was any story at all behind this. sorry I wasn't so specific, I thought it'd be obvious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The Pursuit of Happyness](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454921/) is actually based on the auto biography of [Chris Gardner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Gardner#The_Pursuit_of_Happyness). However the story of the movie is slightly different from the biography.

Here is the few differences between the story of the movie and the biography:

- The Dean Witter internship wasn't unsalaried, but had a $1,000/mo.
  stipend.
- The internship lasted 10 months, not 6.
     Chris Jr. was 18 months old, not preschool aged, when his mother left him with his father.
- They were not rejected from a women's shelter; Glide Memorial, where
  they stayed in the movie and in real life, was a single mothers'
  shelter at the time.
- He did not have to work short hours; in fact he started early and
  stayed late.
- He was a bone scanner salesman, but not self-invested; he quit the
  job before taking the internship.